# \color{white} doesn't work in LaTeXiT

Tags: color, mathcal, latexit

I want to produce a white `\mathcal{L}` in LaTeXiT to then copy and paste into a powerpoint presentation. `\color{blue}` works, but ```color{white} produces nothing - no error, just no result.

The entire code is:

Preamble:

```
   \usepackage{xcolor}
```

Code:

```
\color{blue}%white}
\mathcal{L}
```

and I compile it in Display mode. Can someone help please?

Comment: Hmmm. Is the background also white by any chance??? If so you need to change the background color before you can use white text.

Comment: I haven't specified a background, and when I use the blue colour the background is transparent

Comment: It's working for me with colors other than white since the background is white.

Comment: I notice that when I change the `LaTeXiT` background (Preferences -> General -> Default preview pane background color) to something other than white and typeset `\color{white}\mathcal{L}` the output L moves to the upper left corner of the preview pane and I have to scroll the view to see it. I've never noticed this behavior before.

Comment: Not a solution, because I don't know how LaTeXit works in the background, but I think this has something to do with how the images are cropped. When you use `\color{white}` the size of the resulting image is incorrect also. This is the effect @LaTeXereXeTaL noticed too. You can replicate this by using `\color{black!.05}`. But as soon as you make the threshold slightly higher, it will work. So as a workaround you could use `\color{black!.2}` which will be almost indistinguishable from white.

Comment: I will alert `LaTeXiT`'s developer as he is very responsive to users.

Comment: @AlanMunn unfortunately that doesn't work either

Comment: @BethLong Hmm. It works reliably for me (TL2020 with ghostscript 9.5).

Comment: Using `\color{black!.2}` works in that it gives me an image in the History, but the main viewing window is still white. I can drag the image to the desktop, and I can see the L while dragging, but the resulting image is totally white. Must be something about my setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `LaTeXiT` developer:

"At first sight it is a FAQ : (https://chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-faq.php?lang=en)

My equation seems cropped on the edges, or is not shown at all ; my equation disappears or is not complete when I set it to perfect white.
The cropped edges may only be an illusion : try to display the equation at its real size to be sure.
Otherwise, such a problem certainly comes from Ghostscript, which fails at cropping correctly a white equation on a white background.
For a few pixels missing, use the "Margins" palette and enlarge those ones. And try to use "almost" white color instead of pure white.

Tell me if it is ok.

Best regards,

Pierre Chatelier"

So the culprit may be Ghostscript.

Comment: Yes, and the solution they mention says to use an "almost white" colour, which in my tests works fine.

Comment: @AlanMunn it doesn't seem to work for me on macOS Catalina

Comment: @BethLong What do you mean it doesn't work? There must be *some* threshold at which it does work. Have you found that threshold, and is it not white enough?

Comment: @AlanMunn you're right it does work, the threshold is approximately \color{black!0.3}

Comment: @BethLong I too had to experiment with the color values to find the threshold. When you drag the image off the `LaTeXiT` palette, does it have a transparent background?

Comment: If I copy it it does, if I save it it has a white background, which isn't particularly helpful. But copying it is usually fine, I can save it from ppt anyway so it's no worries

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by defining my color:

````
\definecolor{mylightgray}{rgb}{0.99, 0.99, 0.99}
\color{mylightgray}{y = x}
```
````

Comment: Please note that `\color{myLightgray}` is a switch and only takes one argument, you should thus write `{\color{mylightgray} y = x}`

Comment: For me it works exactly how I posted it (and exactly for the reason you said).  Specifically, this \color{mylightgray} y = x would color only "y"